# ??? .head() displays 5 rows without mentioning it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

*I'm confused here. 
Below is command to view the dataset shape:*

```
   In[] df_faa_dataset.shape
   Out[] (83, 42)
```

*Now I want to see first 5 rows and entered command:*

```
In[] df_faa_dataset.head()
Out[] (displayed output with 5 rows × 42 columns)
```

*How come by default `.head()` method took 5 rows without mentioning in the bracket?*

Answer (score 1):

[Official Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

***copied from documentation***

> ```
> DataFrame.head(n=5)
> Returns first n rows
> ```

It is how we establish default parameter values in python.  For the `head` method, `n=5` means that the default value is 5 and consequently, if you do not pass a parameter value yourself, then 5 is used.